# Python not finding installed module

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pip, vlc

Okay so i wanted to try python and now i wanted to import a package (python-vlc) but it
always tells me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vlc'`
I installed and uninstalled it multiple times now and I am certain that it is installed in my global packages.
I also installed tkinter and that package works like a charm and gets imported without any errors, and eventhough they are in the same folder it wont find vlc.

For Context: I use Pycharm and this is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import vlc


window = Tk()

# window title
window.title("Test")

window.configure(width=800, height=500)
window.configure(bg='#430752')
window.mainloop()
```

I installed it with `pip3 install python-vlc`

Any Idea why Python only finds tkinter and not vlc eventhough they are both installed
with pip and both in the same folder?

Comment: Let me guess: you have multiple Python installations, and the one used in PyCharm is not the one corresponding to `pip3`. Try again, but with `python -m pip install python-vlc`; or whatever the Python command is that you're using in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used `vlc` module in any line. So please try commenting the import statement of vlc using '#'. Then you will get a blank violet coloured `tkinter` window as output.

if you're using windows, then open the command prompt from the start by searching `cmd`, then type `pip install python-vlc` and restart the pycharm IDE.